# How can I reset the time of a postDelayed runnable in onClick?

Tags: android, mobile, onclick

I've got a listView that gets populated from a server. In the onClick of the ListItem, I display a button for a x number of seconds and I make it invisible again. How can I reset the time every time the onClick is called?
Here is my listItem onClick:

```
private void displayInCallButton() {


    mButton.setEnabled(true);

    if (canDisplayInCallControlls) {
        canDisplayInCallControlls = false;

        fadeInAnimation(mButton);
        mButton.setEnabled(true);

        mFrontView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                fadeOutAnimation(mButton);
                mButton.setEnabled(false);
                hasAnimationEnded = true;
                canDisplayInCallControlls = true;


            }
        }, 5000);

    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please explain more `reset the time every time the onClick is called` line

Comment: you cannot  do that,  you need to remove pending callback and post it again

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to remove the callbacks and set it once again with the new one with the reset time.

first, set the call back like

```
Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
    fadeOutAnimation(mButton);
    mButton.setEnabled(false);
    hasAnimationEnded = true;
    canDisplayInCallControlls = true;
   }
};
```

then set it to mFrontView like,

```
mFrontView.postDelayed(myRunnable,5000)
```

If you want to reset, do it like

```
mFrontView.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
mFrontView.postDelayed(myRunnable, 2000);
```

Answer (score 3):

> How can I reset the time every time the onClick is called?

There is no built-in mechanism to accomplish that.

You can, however, keep a reference to the `Runnable` you post, remove it and then repost it again to restart at the original delay.

The result would look somewhat like this in its most simple form:

```
Runnable mDelayedRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
            fadeOutAnimation(mButton);
            mButton.setEnabled(false);
            hasAnimationEnded = true;
            canDisplayInCallControlls = true;
        }
    };

private void displayInCallButton() {
    mButton.setEnabled(true);

    if (canDisplayInCallControlls) {
        canDisplayInCallControlls = false;

        fadeInAnimation(mButton);
        mButton.setEnabled(true);

        mFrontView.removeCallbacks(mDelayedRunnable);
        mFrontView.postDelayed(mDelayedRunnable, 5000);
    }
}
```

You can safely call `removeCallbacks()` with a `Runnable` that was never posted in the first place (or even `null`).

If you don't want to keep an explicit reference to the `Runnable`, you could also opt to tag the view with it. Just don't forget to clean up on i.e. orientation changes and the like.